# Input validation doesn't work in Spring + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and I explore it using "Spring in action 5" book. I do similar actions with my website, I have written 2 controllers and 2 html files for pages. The first page is a form for pizza creation. the second is order submission. My code for controllers is practically the same as in the book.  Everything worked fine until I started to validate form inputs. I did everything that needed in Pizza, Order classes and controllers.

Order class:

```
@Data
public class Order {
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Street os required")
    private String street;

    @NotBlank(message = "City is required")
    private String city;

    @NotBlank(message = "State is required")
    private String state;

    @NotBlank(message = "Zip is required")
    private String zip;

    @CreditCardNumber(message = "Not a valid credit card number")
    private String ccNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$")
    private String ccExpiration;

    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, message = "Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;
}
```

Pizza class:

```
@Data
public class Pizza {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Name must be at least 3 characters long")
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 1, message = "You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Controller for pizza creation:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/create")
public class CreatePizzaController {
    @GetMapping
    public String showCreationForm(Model model){
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new Ingredient("CLS22", "Classic base 22cm", Ingredient.Type.BASIC),
                new Ingredient("CLS30", "Classic base 30cm", Ingredient.Type.BASIC),
                new Ingredient("PEPE", "Pepperoni", Ingredient.Type.MEAT),
                new Ingredient("HAM", "Ham", Ingredient.Type.MEAT),
                new Ingredient("CHMPG", "Champignons", Ingredient.Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("CUCU", "Cucumbers", Ingredient.Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("PARM", "Parmesan cheese", Ingredient.Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("MOZ", "Mozzarella cheese", Ingredient.Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("BARBS", "Barbecue sauce", Ingredient.Type.SAUCE),
                new Ingredient("TOMAS", "Tomato sauce", Ingredient.Type.SAUCE)
                );

        Ingredient.Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for(Ingredient.Type type: types){
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
        model.addAttribute("create", new Pizza());
        return "create";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processCreation(@Valid Pizza pizza, Errors errors){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "create";
        }
        //Save creation...
        log.info("Processing creation: " + pizza);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    private List<Ingredient> filterByType(List<Ingredient> ingredients, Ingredient.Type type) {
        List<Ingredient> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Ingredient ingredient:ingredients){
            if(ingredient.getType() == type){
                filtered.add(ingredient);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

Controller for the form submission:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        return "orderForm";
    }
    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "orderForm";
        }
        log.info("Order submitted: " + order);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

The problem is in validating pizza creation. When I enter invalid name of the pizza and click button to submit my pizza I get Whitelabel Error Page.

```
2021-03-11 21:48:56.740 ERROR 124 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/create.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'create' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

It seems like I am not working properly with attributes in my *CreatePizzaController* class, it must be broken, though I'll give html code below. I tried to replace *Errors* parameter in *processCreation* method to *BindingResult* parameter and check for erros but it works the same. Please help me, I don't really understand why my code doesn't work with input validation.

orderForm.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${order}">
    <h1>Order your pizza creations!</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/pizza_logo.jpg}"/>
    <a th:href="@{/create}" id="another">Create another pizza</a><br/>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
        <span class="validationError">Please correct the problems below and resubmit.</span>
    </div>
    <h3>Deliver my pizza masterpiece to...</h3>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="street">Street address: </label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{street}"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="city">City: </label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{city}"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="state">State: </label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{state}"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="zip">Zip code: </label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{zip}"/>
    <br/>

    <h3>Here's how I'll pay...</h3>
    <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccNumber')}"
          th:errors="*{ccNumber}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccExpiration')}"
          th:errors="*{ccExpiration}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit order"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

create.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/style.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>Create your pizza:</h3>
<img th:src="@{/images/pizza_logo.jpg}" width="200" height="200"/>

<form method="post" th:object="${create}">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="basics">
            <h3>Choose the basic: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${basic}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="radio" checked th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="meat">
            <h3>Choose meat: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${meat}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
            <h3>Choose vegetables: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauce">
            <h3>Choose sauce: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheese">
            <h3>Choose cheese: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-button">
        <h3>Name your pizza:</h3>
        <input class="submit-field" type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <br/>
        <button>Submit your pizza</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S
Adding @ModelAttribute annotation worked, my problem is solved. But now I get another problem related to thymeleaf. When I add thymeleaf code to handle input error and I try to enter invalid name of pizza, thymeleaf just doesn't generate my checkboxes. Here is create.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/style.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>Create your pizza:</h3>
<img th:src="@{/images/pizza_logo.jpg}" width="200" height="200"/>

<form method="post" th:object="${create}">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="basics">
            <h3>Choose the basic: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${basic}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="radio" checked th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="meat">
            <h3>Choose meat: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${meat}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
            <h3>Choose vegetables: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauce">
            <h3>Choose sauce: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheese">
            <h3>Choose cheese: </h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span class="checktext" th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-button">
        <h3>Name your pizza:</h3>
        <input class="submit-field" type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <span class="validationError"
              th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
              th:errors="*{name}">Error</span>
        <br/>
        <button>Submit your pizza</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine until I click submit button with invalid name field. After that my error message appears, there are no exceptions as well as my checkboxes.
[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmxGX.png)
[and this is generated html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npKUD.png)

Comment: Even if it doesn't address your problem, you should be using BindingResult rather than Errors.

Comment: A comment for future requests.. As this is very long, it would have been easier for reading if you pushed code to github.

Comment: @bliss I posted the recent problem with generating divs to the new question which you can see here: [new problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66610802/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-divs-on-the-page-are-not-generated)

Comment: @SlavaUgnachyov I responded to your new post. Sorry about not responding here yesterday, I missed your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @ModelAttribute annotation:

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("create") Pizza pizza
@Valid @ModelAttribute("order") Order order
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But I don't actually get how this works. And after that I get another problem, which I guess is related to thymeleaf. I added this code to create.html to handle error, but after that my checkboxes doesn't appear if I click button
`<input class="submit-field" type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
<span class="validationError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors={name}">Error</span>
<br/>
<button>Submit your pizza</button>`
These divs just  don't generate:
`<div th:each="ingredient : ${basic}">`

Comment: You've previously added these objects to the model: "model.addAttribute("create", new Pizza());". The @ModelAttribute annotation indicates that a Pizza object called "create" needs to be retrieved from the model. Also, do you mind editing your post with the new code? It's a bit hard to read as a comment.

Comment: @SlavaUgnachyov Are you getting a Thymeleaf parsing exception that you can show me? As far as I'm aware all you need to set for the relevant input are th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')} and th:errorclass="validationError".

Comment: I edited my post, you can see full html code there. I don't get any exceptions, my checkboxes just don't generate. I add error handling into span.As I understand, you offer adding _th:errorclass="validationError"_ instead _<span class="validationError"_ but it doesn't help for me if I am right. The same is if I add _th:errorclass_ into input tag. If I replace _th:errors={name}_ with _th:errorclass_ in my span I get parse error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to extract the hardcoded part inside method showCreationForm() to another method and annotate it with @ModelAttribute.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

And use Use the @ModelAttribute annotation:

---

[image]

---

You can see the full example here on my github [link-repo](https://github.com/lalik77/pizza.git)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" th:object="${create}">
```

Looking at the code above,
You should try this -> (@Valid Pizza **create**, Errors errors)

```
@PostMapping
public String processCreation(@Valid Pizza create, Errors errors){
    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        return "create";
    }
    //Save creation...
    log.info("Processing creation: " + create);
    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
```

I think the naming of objects and templates in Spring in Action 5 doesn't help.

For example, you could rename the HTML template to createForm.html, or simply rename the objects.